# Add custom header in apache2 before proxyPass

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, apache2.4

In apache before proxy I want to add an authentication header for aws signature.
So basically it should add the following headers

```
x-amz-date   : date
Authorization : AWS access_key:aws_signature
```

This aws signature will require a program to get generated.

What possible options we can use to link apache2 to add this auth headers?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not dynamic, and the Apache config doesn't care about these headers on input, you can just use `RequestHeader`:

```
RequestHeader set x-amz-date date early
RequestHeader set Authorization "AWS access_key:aws_signature" early
```

If either value is dynamic, use "expr=..." as the value value to pull the dynamic bits you need.

Comment: This requires to be dynamically generated.